# FPGA packaging and performance

Tags: fpga, timing, packages

I would like begin a new custom FPGA design and I am considering buying a dev kit for experimentation. When the design has finished, I intend to design a dedicated PCB board. If I change the packaging of the model and instead of a BGA move to QFP, which is easier and cheaper for me to work with, will it drastically affect my timings when I will adjust my design to it? How significant is the packaging of a FPGA related to timing for same models?

I wouldn't like to to invest a fair amount of time and money on dev kit and then find out that I don't meet the timing requirements. I know it's a little vague as a question, but I am looking to get a sense on what to expect. Thank you.

Comment: A little vague? You say you're concerned about timing, but you haven't described your timing requirements at all! But unless you're doing something VERY esoteric, the timing differences among packages will be negligible.

Comment: Also, [delays can be compensated for](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/520985/11683).